# Can I apply exp function directly on a list or matrix?

Tags: python, exponential

Can I raise a list to the power of e Like

```
np.exp(L)
```

instead of using a for loop for every single element? And does it apply to Arrays and Matrices too?

Comment: Try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like yes, yes you can

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.exp(L)
array([  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692,  54.59815003,
       148.4131591 ])
```

even if it's just a plain list and not a numpy array:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> np.exp(L)
array([  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692,  54.59815003,
       148.4131591 ])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of loop if think you can use np.vectorize()

[Speeding up your code (2): vectorizing the loops with Numpy](https://hackernoon.com/speeding-up-your-code-2-vectorizing-the-loops-with-numpy-e380e939bed3)